# How to extract text that has been added to a string in R

Tags: r, string, substring, extract

I have a string with a known format, something like:

```
"This string will have additional text here *, and it will have more here ^, and finally there will be more here ~ with some text after."
```

and a piece of data will be

```
"This string will have additional text here about things, and it will have more here regarding other stuff, and finally there will be more here near the end with some text after."
```

where the inserted text will not always be the same length. I need a way to identify what each of *, ^, ~ are equal to in the second string:

```
* = "about things"
^ = "regarding other stuff"
~ = "near the end"
```

The new string won't have the text delimited by anything but the template string will hopefully have unique enough text between each optional bit that you can identify that each time.

I've tried looking around but cannot find anything similar to what I'm asking to even get started, any package or function would be really helpful!

Comment: I can imagine a way of doing this with regex, which would also be very error prone.  Can you tell us more about how you ended up with this problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Regex was in my mind, as well as maybe finding the start and end of each known bit of the string, but also potentially error prone. Unfortunately someone decided to collect some feedback using a drop down template (with the option of free text...) and only save the full text. Going forward I've added a character before and after to make it easier but still got a load from before the change I need to work through :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not now if it is the best solution, but I would replace the known parts with a delimiter (or nothing at the beginning and and) and than split the resulting text by that delimiter.

```
text = "This string will have additional text here about things, and it will have more here regarding other stuff, and finally there will be more here near the end with some text after."
temp = gsub("This string will have additional text here ", "", text)
temp = gsub(", and it will have more here ", "^", temp)
temp = gsub(", and finally there will be more here ", "^", temp)
temp = gsub(" with some text after.", "", temp)
solution = unlist(strsplit(temp, "\\^"))
solution
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight variation on [@Benjamin Schlegel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51156131/2114932) using the [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/) package that keeps the known parts and their replacements (visually) closer together.

```r
library(stringr)

text <- "This string will have additional text here about things, and it will have more here regarding other stuff, and finally there will be more here near the end with some text after."

text_repl <-
  str_replace_all(
    text,
    c(
      "This string will have additional text here " = "",
      ", and it will have more here "               = "^",
      ", and finally there will be more here "      = "^",
      " with some text after."                      = ""
    )
  )

str_split(text_repl, "\\^", simplify = TRUE)
#>      [,1]           [,2]                    [,3]          
#> [1,] "about things" "regarding other stuff" "near the end"
```

`str_split()` returns either a list of character vectors (`simplify = FALSE`) or a character matrix (`simplify = TRUE`), which can easily be turned into a data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can look into unique patterns of words before and after the ~, * and ^ etc., and put these in a vector like this:

```
priorstrings <- c("text here", "have more here", "be more here")
afterstrings <- c("and it", "and finally", "with some")
```

Then check whether these are actually unique by checking whether

```
length(unique(priorstrings)) == length(priorstrings)
length(unique(afterstrings)) == length(afterstrings)
```

both evaluate to TRUE.

Then paste these together with a look around inbetween, like this:

```
fullsearches <- paste0(priorstrings, " (.*? )" , afterstrings)
```

I used your example string again, named it y, and added another named z:

```
y <- "This string will have additional text here about things, and it will have more here regarding other stuff, and finally there will be more here near the end with some text after."
z <- "This string will have additional text here on this topic, and it will have more here to follow up, and finally there will be more here to finish with some text after."
```

Then, finally, do something like this:

```
sapply(list(y,z), function(x) str_match(x, fullsearches)[,2])
```

That gives:

```
     [,1]                      [,2]             
[1,] "about things, "          "on this topic, "
[2,] "regarding other stuff, " "to follow up, " 
[3,] "near the end "           "to finish "
```

I think you can totally add more priorstrings, afterstrings and fullsearchers this way, and also apply this to larger lists of strings.